# Django delete objects with no relations

Tags: django, django-models

I have been trying to find a function/sample code that would delete from table all objects with no relations to different objects (I use many-to-many relationship). Documentation and google were not helpful. Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you please share relevant details of your model together with sample data and expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
table.objects.filter(mtom=None).delete()
```